# how to deploy java web application to AWS elastic beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I wrote a AWS java web project, and it could run on my local server.

But when I refer to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Java.sdlc.html

to deploy the application on elastic beanstalk. I could only got a blank page. I also tried upload WAR file to elastic beanstalk, but still got an blank page.

I SSH into the EC2 instance, and find no folders for my application. I think there should be somewhere in tomcat7/myapp folder. Could anyone tell me why, and how to deploy java app to it?

I also try the travelLog example, but still cannot get the page display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try a different JRE 1.6 and now I could post my application.

It is really weird, I don't know why JRE 1.7 doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Quick facts about elastic beanstalk:

1. On beanstalk instances by default installed java open sdk.
2. In the folder: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks you can find scripts which do deploy
3. By default beanstalk deploy application to the /var/lib/tomcat6/

Comment: I actually select tomcat7, and use my JRE 1.7. But it doesn't work. But when I change window->preference->installed JRE, to JRE 1.6, it works. I really don't know why.